# JMeter recording for browser less application

Tags: jmeter

My web application doesn't uses browser. It is a MS Word plugin and uses port 80.
When I try to record on port 80, Jmeter says 'port already in use'
And if i set other port in my app, app doesn't work properly.
What to do in this case??

Thanks

Comment: *When I try to record on port 80* how did you do that?

Comment: By setting port 80 in JMeter's Test Script recorder.

Answer (score 1):

- If your MS Word Plugin has proxy settings - configure it to use JMeter's Proxy.
- If it doesn't have its own proxy settings - it should respect system proxy configuration (usually it can be configured via Internet Explorer proxy settings)
- You can use 3rd-party tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the traffic and [convert](http://converter.blazemeter.com/) it to JMeter .jmx script.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do it as I see it is not through script recording but by setting requests in jMeter manually and build whole test plan like this. It's not so hard anyway if you know how your plugin works and requests you send. Some short info can be find here:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html

Answer (score 0):

Error message 'port already in use' means that port 80 was assinged to some other service. You can't assign that port to Jmeter proxy server to start. (Jmeter has to start its own service on some unused port)

a. Just start Jmeter on its default port 8080 (or some other unused port).

b. Redirect required traffic to Jmeter proxy port (i.e, 8080). MS office will honor System proxy settings, so change the IE proxy setting to server '127.0.0.1' port '8080', it should automatically apply to office.

[image: IE_PROXY_SETTING]

c. Now all the HTTP requests trigger from Office should visible in Jmeter Proxy recorder. After that you can move them to required location in Test Plan.

As Dmitri Said, you can also use Fiddler to track the requests (Prefer Fiddler over Wireshark, for its ease of use).

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable replies. I am trying Fiddler and will share my experience later.